# Formtastic pre-check few checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, formtastic

I'm trying to manually tell formtastic to check a few checkboxes. `@some_array` currently has an element called `checked` which exists for each member.

```
= f.input :cboxes, label: "CBoxes", as: :check_boxes, 
    collection: @some_array.map { |a| [a[:name], a[:id]] }
```

I've tried to set the `input_html` to `{ checked: 'checked' }` ([How to pre-check checkboxes in formtastic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734951/how-to-pre-check-checkboxes-in-formtastic)) but this checks all checkboxes, not just the select few that I want.

The contents of `@some_array` are coming via an API, and I can't change the database structure ([Ruby on Rails + Formtastic: Not checking checkboxes for multiple checked answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696376/ruby-on-rails-formtastic-not-checking-checkboxes-for-multiple-checked-answers))

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are editing an ActiveModel, you don't need to "manually select checkboxes".

Let's consider a simple example with a single `User` model which has fields `username` and `roles`. Roles field is a string column, which Rails serializes as an Array. It might also be `has_many` relation to other ActiveModel, but we assume it's an Array for simplicity.

`User` is defined in `user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :roles, Array
end
```

Now you can "assign manually" desired roles to `User` in your controller:

```
@user = User.new(username: 'dimakura', roles: ['admin', 'editor'])
```

and define form in your view:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username %>
  <%= f.input :roles, as: :check_boxes, collection: ['owner', 'admin', 'editor', 'viewer'] %>
<% end %>
```

In given example only "admin" and "editor" roles will be pre-selected in form. The "owner" and "viewer" role won't be selected.

**Update** [Official documentation](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) states:

> Formtastic, much like Rails, is very ActiveRecord-centric.

But actually it's not a big challenge to create ActiveRecord-compatible model yourself. An example of doing this can be found in this [blog post](http://dondoh.tumblr.com/post/4142258573/formtastic-without-activerecord).

Comment: This would work, yeah. But I'm not using an ActiveModel. The array structure is:`[{name: "some name", id: 123, checked: "checked"}]`

Comment: @AshishKumar what is a model you assign this field to?

Comment: There is no model class. I'm getting the data via an external API. Since I can't control changes in the data on the service side, I can't save it to database.

Comment: @AshishKumar well, the way to go is to implement `ActiveRecord` compatible class yourself. See example link in updated answer